# in Bash: how to echo alphabet in multiple lines from A to E then in a new line from F to J and so on

Tags: bash, loops, grid, nested-loops, indexed

I have tried

```
declare -a arr=( {A..Y} )
for j in {06..10}; do
        echo -n "$j "
        for (( i=0; i<25; i++ )); do
                if [ $i -eq 4 ]; then
                        echo -n "${arr[$i]}${arr[$i]}"
                        break
                else
                        echo -n "${arr[$i]}${arr[$i]}"
                        echo -n " "
                fi
        done
        echo
done
```

but I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlqHK.png)

Also tried

```
declare -a arr=( {A..Y} )
for j in {06..10}; do
        echo -n "$j "
        for (( i=0; i<25; i++ )); do
                echo -n "${arr[$i]}"
                echo -n " "
        done
        echo
done
```

But I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWALa.png)

Thank you

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bash array slice:

```sh
declare -a arr=( {A..Y} )
n=5
for ((i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i = i + n))
do
    echo "${arr[@]:i:n}"
done
```

```
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
P Q R S T
U V W X Y
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternate method using common 'nix tools and no shell loop:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {A..Y} | nl -nrz -s' ' -v6 -w2
```

Explanations:

- `printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {A..Y}`: Prints formatted 5 string arguments `%s` separated by a space   and ending with a new-line `\n`.

  As the `printf` consumes only 5 arguments at a time out of the 25 generated by the Bash's bracket expression `{A..Y}`, the format will be applied to each group of 5 arguments, resulting in this output:

  ```
  A B C D E
  F G H I J
  K L M N O
  P Q R S T
  U V W X Y
  ```
- `| nl -nrz -s' ' -v6 -w2`: Streams the above to the `nl` command to add line numbers.

  - `-nrz`: Formats `n`umbers `r`ight-aligned with `z`ero padding.
  - `-s' '`: `s`eparates numbering from text with a blank  .
  - `-v6`: Starts numbering at `6`.
  - `-w2`: Number `w`idth `2`.

Final result:

```
06 A B C D E
07 F G H I J
08 K L M N O
09 P Q R S T
10 U V W X Y
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know of `nl` +1

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simpler if you keep a separate variable to count how many you've printed already and print a newline when you've printed 6 characters.

Example:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=( {A..Y} )

count=0;
for ch in "${arr[@]}"
do
    echo -n "$ch "

    (( count = (count + 1) % 5 ))

    if (( count == 0 )) ; then
        # 6 characters printed, now print a newline
        echo
    fi
done
```

An alternative using an index variable in the loop instead:

```sh
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#arr[@]}; ++idx)); do
    echo -n "${arr[$idx]} "

    if (( (idx+1) % 5 == 0 )); then
        echo
    fi
done
```

Both output:

```
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
P Q R S T
U V W X Y
```

If you want `06...10` to be printed first on each line:

```
step=5
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#arr[@]}; ++idx)); do
    if (( (idx) % step == 0 )); then
        (( pre = idx/step + 6 ))
        printf "%02d " "$pre"
    fi

    echo -n "${arr[$idx]} "

    if (( (idx+1) % step == 0 )); then
        echo
    fi
done
```

Or simpler

```
step=5
for ((idx = 0; idx < ${#arr[@]}; idx += step)); do
    (( pre = idx/step + 6 ))
    printf "%02d " "$pre"
    echo  "${arr[@]:idx:step}"
done
```

Output:

```
06 A B C D E
07 F G H I J
08 K L M N O
09 P Q R S T
10 U V W X Y
```

Comment: or  `printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {A..Y}`

Comment: @LéaGris Wow :-) Can you combine that to get the `06..10` prefix too?

Comment: `printf '%s %s %s %s %s\n' {A..Y} | nl -nrz -s' ' -v6 -w2`

Comment: @LéaGris Nice! Put it up as an answer and you'll have my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```sh
printf '%s\n' {A..Y} | paste -d ' ' - - - - -
```

Or with plain bash

```sh
alphabet=({A..Y})
for i in "${!alphabet[@]}"; do
    ((i % 5 == 4)) && sep=$'\n' || sep=' '
    printf '%s%s' "${alphabet[i]}" "$sep"
done
```